# I'm trying to run an Express static middleware from this book, and I cannot see what the example is trying to show

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm on a section in this book about Express where it mentions express.static to serve files, but each time I run it, I get the code catching when no file is found. I have made a folder called public and put in an HTML file, and had it both in the project folder and above it but nothing happens other than the message given after it runs the static method call.

The code is:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var http = require("http");

var app = express();

var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname,"public");
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

app.use(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.end("Looks like you didn't find a static file");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

The book does not give much more explanation. I've never worked with servers. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your sample code and was able to get it to display HTML files created in a `public` directory in the project root.

Eg. `public/page.html` could be retrieved at `localhost:3000/page.html`

If you create an `index.html` file in your public directory it will be retrieved at `localhost:3000`. The index does not need the full `.html` extension.

Comment: thank you! The book should've been clearer that when trying to see it in the browser, it needed to NOT be **/public/**page.html